# Immediate window requires an object reference?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to call a public function inside a class using the immediate window using the following:

```
?LeadFunctions.Duplicate(2)
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

The function is defined inside my LeadFunctions class, and is a public function. Why does this not work?

Comment: "LeadFunctions" is a type name, not an object reference.  Typing `new LeadFunctions().Duplicate(2)` will work for example.

Comment: That gives me a syntax error?